# Segregating to 3 tiers from existing ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net project currently i have business logic and and data access code in two sub folders(BLL,DAL) which are itself located web site project's app_code folder. I need to segregate them to two separate projects(one project for business layer and one project for Data access code).

1. How can I maintain connection strings necessary to Data access project which are currently in web.config file?(i.e if I choose Class library template for creating DAL and BLL projects)
2. How can I maintain various other web.config key values that are currently used in BLL, DAL code files?
3. How can I deploy compiled project? (ie Web site project I am currently deploying bin folder to Staging> production but this way where should i put DAL.dll and BLL.dll and relevant config files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 2) Add a 'using System.Configuration' and just reference them. Since their referenced in the project, asp.net will pick it up.

For example:

```
using System.Configuration;
    namespace DataLayer
    {
        public class BaseDataAccess
        {        
            public static string ConnectionString_Logging
            {
                get
                {
                    return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString_Logging_Legacy"].ToString();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

3) If properly referenced, upon compile, your BLL and DAL dlls will be in your bin folder of the main/ui project. If using web.config, your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you should be wrapping those configuration bits up in objects along the way. But in any case, you can move them to a different class project without worry here -- it will pick up the configuration settings from whatever project it is hosted by, so you don't need to somehow provide the configuration to your library.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code should work, as the settings are read from the Config file of the running process, in this case your `Web.Config`, however i suggest you use [custom configuration settings](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020133931/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032807-1.aspx), these would be read from your `Web.Config` file, a typical implementation could look something like :

```
<YourCompany>
    <YourCompany.ProjectName>
          <Data ConnectionName="NameOfConnectionToUse" SomethingElse="XZY" />
          <Business SomeValue="12345" />
    </YourCompany.ProjectName>
</YourCompany>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into ideal settings/custom config etc, as asked - during runtime, your class libraries will get the configuration from the web.config if referenced as such from within these layers with no change. System.Configuration.AppSettings/ConnectionStrings will still work.